# Flex Magento connection using SOAP

Tags: apache-flex, magento, actionscript, soap, flex4

I am trying to connect Flex with Magento using SOAP API. but i am stuck with an error:

```
faultCode:EncodingError.
faultString: Array of input arguments did not contain a required parameter at position 1.
```

I am requesting login function of magento like this:

```
xmlRequest = <'login'><'username'>username'<'/username'><'apiKey'>apiKey<'/apiKey'><'/login'>";
```

What is the correct way to call login function of magento using soap from FLex?

How can i get rid of the above error?

Comment: try this link : http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/630-connecting-to-magento-with-soap-part-2

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/&/viewthread/46321/#t236025